# How was this amazing drupal performance presentation done?

Tags: javascript, performance

How was this amazing drupal performance presentation ( http://rupl.github.com/high-performance-theming ) was done? Which jQ libraries are needed? And what is the best place to ask?

Thanks

Amnon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing overly complicated; the 3d navigation makes use of the [reveal.js library](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/).

> reveal.js is a framework for easily creating beautiful presentations using HTML.

And then there are a few helper libraries:

- [`Highlight.js`](http://softwaremaniacs.org/soft/highlight/en/) - for syntax highlighting
- [`classList.js`](https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js) - adds element.classList support to browsers that don't support it
- `carousel.js` - seems to be custom DOM helper functions.

Reveal is pretty easy to use, it just requires a lot of patience and a will to succeed. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Clive for pointing me in the right direction. To expand your answer, I have found http://rvl.io/ to be a pretty easy online editor for reveal.js. Also, there is a PDF export ability for printout. 

Other options are mentioned in [this post](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-free-html5-presentation-systems/) - especially intresting is impress.js - which has a [new drupal module](http://drupalmodules.com/module/impress-3d) associated with it which allows to save slides as nodes.